# want to fetch video current playing time and total time of video from avplayer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayer

i am implementing `AVPlayer` for playing video with in my app and i played video success fully now i want video total time and current playing time continuously so for that i have tried some way let me show you

I have tried using `NotificationCenter` but for that i am getting 0.0 every time and after some time i am getting crash let me show you my code

Here is my videoPlaying code

```
 func videoPlay(){
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
        self.addChild(playerController)
        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 375, height: 207)
        player.play()
        if player.rate != 0 && player.error == nil {
            print("video player is playing.................")
              NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(gettime(_:)),name: nil,object: nil)
        } else {
            print("video player is NOT playing.")
        }
    }
```

and here i am trying to get time from video like below

```
@objc func gettime(_ notification: Notification){
        let currentTime = Float(player.currentTime().value)
        print(currentTime)
    }
```

but still i am not getting current playing time i am getting crash and give below error

**Error**

`Thread 8: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffff7ac4eef)`

Comment: I copy pasted your exact code and it works fine. Can you provide the URL for the stream you are trying to play?

Comment: @SeanIngeAsbjørnsen Yes sure here is my url `https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4`

Comment: my code is still giving me error can you please provide you vieoURL

Comment: It works fine here with that URL as well. Here is my complete code for reference: https://pastebin.com/Phz9aG35

Answer (score 1):

define a label `currentTimeLable` in your view and use this code

```
 let interval = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 2)
            player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (progressTime) in

                let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)
                let secondString = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds) % 60)
                let minutString = String(format: "%02d", Int(seconds) / 60)
                self.currentTimeLabel.text = "\(minutString):\(secondString)"
```

Comment: Thank this help full for me but now i want to diplay that time on tableview how can i show on table view please help me

Comment: var currentTimeLabel: UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    //use the right possion that is in your video
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 20, height: 20)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}

playerController.view.addsubview(currentTimeLabel)

//BTW: it's better to use container and add a player as a subview to that container instead of playerController.view

Comment: but what if i want to display this second and minute to tableview cell

Comment: In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath func` send data to your label for example: `currentTimeLabel.text = secondString

Comment: but if you have model, you should create a variable in your cell class and send data to that variable

Answer (score 0):

Try below code you will get the total duration of playing item. And you need to wait for player ready to play your item, For that you need to add observer of

In your **viewDidLoad** Method add following code.

```
player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: [], context: nil)
```

Once your player is ready to play item(video) the **observeValue(forKeyPath)** called you will get total time in **getTotalTime()** method.

```
func getTotalTime() 
   if let seconds = player?.currentItem?.asset.duration {
      let totalTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(seconds)
      if let currentTime = player?.currentTime() {
             let time = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentTime)
      }
   }
}
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if keyPath == "status" {
        if player?.status == AVPlayerStatus.readyToPlay {
          getTotalTime() 
        } else if player?.status == AVPlayerStatus.failed {}
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CMTime'`

Comment: please check i have edit your answer at which line i am getting error

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with `addPeriodicTimeObserver` Observer like below:

```
 self.player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 2), queue: DispatchQueue.main) {[weak self] (progressTime) in
          if let duration = self!.player.currentItem?.duration {
               let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
               let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(progressTime)
               print(seconds)
           }
 }
```